# mount vdhx image on ubuntu (data recovery)

Tags: mount

I used to use windows 10 and made a backup (vdhx) of it on a external drive. Under the naive impression that data recovering from this image to ubuntu would be more straight forward I changed to ubuntu and now it is not straight forward.

Could someone explain to me how I can mount this image in ubuntu to look through my stuff and get what I need? Since I am a new to ubuntu a gui option would be highly appreciated but comandline would (with help) also work.

I already tried this (among others):

```
guestmount -a /path_to_external_drive/file.vhdx --inspector --ro mnt/vhd/
```

(based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819474/how-can-i-attach-a-vhdx-or-vhd-file-in-linux)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Here are examples for a file that is called **myvhdxfile.vhdx** that is mounted to **/mnt/vhdxdrive**

**Example 1.** Where guestmount is inspecting (-i) the disks looking for an operating system and mount filesystems:

1. Install `sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools`
2. Create a mountpoint e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/vhdxdrive`
3. Run `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx -i --rw /mnt/vhdxdrive`
4. (optional when you are done inspecting the files) To unmount run `sudo guestunmount /mnt/vhdxdrive`

**Example 2.** If you run into the error: **guestmount: no operating system was found on this disk** you can mount individual partitions by following these steps:

1. Run `sudo guestfish --rw -a myvhdxfile.vhdx`
2. Type in `run` and hit enter
3. Type in `list-filesystems` and hit enter and note the path to the partition
4. Type in `exit` and hit enter

The output of the above steps might look like this:

```
><fs> run
><fs> list-filesystems 
/dev/sda2: ntfs
><fs> exit
```

Finally, you can mount the partition `/dev/sda2` by running:

- `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx --rw /mnt/vhdxdrive -m /dev/sda2`

If you got a different partition path from running the *list-filesystems* command in guestfish than you should replace `/dev/sda2` with this path in the above command.

**Example 3.**
If you want the mounted partition to pup up in files (nautilus) and be able to access it with your personal user account:

1. Create a mountpoint in media `sudo mkdir /media/vhdxdrive`
2. Mount with user permissions `sudo guestmount --add myvhdxfile.vhdx -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o allow_other --rw /media/vhdxdrive -m /dev/sda2`

Change the uid and gid values to the corresponding ids of your user in above command.

Comment: Thanks to this I could mount a Windows 11 WSL2 Ubuntu partition from a separate (dual boot) Ubuntu. found in /media/raul/6E1847B818477E59/Users/RaulSalinas/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/ext4.vhdx

Answer (score 1):

The first time I tried this I got:

```
libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1.
To see full error messages you may need to enable debugging.
Do:
  export LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1 LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1
and run the command again.  For further information, read:
  http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#debugging-libguestfs
You can also run 'libguestfs-test-tool' and post the *complete* output
into a bug report or message to the libguestfs mailing list.
```

If this happens to you, and you're operating as a regular (i.e. non-root) user, you may not have permission to read the kernel. To check this, do:

```bash
ls -l /boot/vmlinux-`uname-r`
```

If it shows up as, e.g.

```
-rw------- 1 root root 11399928 Nov 12 02:51 /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-23-generic
```

then you don't have permission to read the kernel. To correct this, either run `guestmount` as root with `sudo`, or do:

```bash
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 0644 /boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r`
```

The latter will make the kernel world-readable and will allow you to use `guestmount`. Note that having the kernel world-readable may be a security risk, so do some reading if you're worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it a bit more and could solve it. 
the changes were: 
- change mountpoint to folder in home directory
- there were 3 vhdx images created in the backup and apparently only contains the data I needed. (I am still unsure what the other ones are.)