How can I access the WSL root file system from Linux partition in a dual boot set up?
Let me explain real quick how my machine is built before explaining my problem:

I've got a dual boot setup with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS both installed in my main drive C:\.
Within Windows 11 I also have installed a WSL Ubuntu 22.04 in my second drive D:\wsl\Ubuntu\ext4.vhdx (Initially I installed in C:\ and then I moved it to D:\ (Moving WSL Distribution to Another Drive) cause I thought that it would be more easily to access the root file system from my Ubuntu 24.04 being there as an "external drive").

I know how to access the root file system from my Windows 11 runnning following instructions/commands:

I can run explorer.exe . from my WSL Ubuntu Terminal in Windows.
I can navigate through \\wsl$\Ubuntu in my File Explorer.

What I really want is to access the WSL Ubuntu 22.04 from my Ubuntu 24.04 LTS partition but I'm unable to, from that partition I can navigate through C:\ or D:\ without issues/
I'm aware there's a folder in %localappdata%\Packages\Canonical...\LocalState where the root file system are supposed to be located but in Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11 are empty.

Isn't there any way to boot/mount the ext4.vhdx file in Ubuntu to achieve this or isn't possible at all?

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088411/mount-vdhx-image-on-ubuntu-data-recovery

extremely risky: https://blog.codybunch.com/2020/10/16/WSL2-Mount-vhdx-to-WSL2/  The kernel alterations is a security breach waiting to happen.
